# Why custom drawRect is not shown in 6.1 simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, drawrect

There is a UIView subclass (`ThumbView`) inside a `UICollectionViewCell`. The following code works great in iOS 7 simulator:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ThumbView *thumbView = (ThumbView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [thumbView setNeedsDisplay];
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

However, in the iOS 6 version of the simulator:

The grids are all gone:

[image]

I have put a `NSLog` in the `drawRect` of the ThumbView to make sure `drawRect` is called.

What is wrong?

- Xcode Version 5.0 (5A1412)
- iOS Simulator Version 7.0 (463.9.4)

UPDATE (the drawing code):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
   [self drawGrid:rect];
}

- (void)drawGrid:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat margin = self.margin;
    CGFloat lineWidth = 2.0;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect gridRect = CGRectInset(rect, margin, margin);

    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        CGFloat h = gridRect.size.height / 9;
        CGFloat y = i * h;
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, margin, y+margin);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, gridRect.size.width+margin, y+margin);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth/4.0);
        if (i == 3 || i == 6) {
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.darkGrayColor.CGColor);
        } else {
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.lightGrayColor.CGColor);
        }
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        CGFloat w = gridRect.size.width / 9;
        CGFloat x = i * w;
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x+margin, margin);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x+margin, gridRect.size.height+margin);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth/4.0);
        if (i == 3 || i == 6) {
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.darkGrayColor.CGColor);
        } else {
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.lightGrayColor.CGColor);
        }
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

    CGFloat frameWidth = lineWidth * 2.0;
    CGRect frameRect = CGRectInset(rect, 0.0, 0.0);
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) frameWidth = lineWidth * 2.0;
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, frameWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.darkGrayColor.CGColor);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, frameRect);
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your question because method name is `drawRect:`?

Comment: typo is only in the question, fixed. thanks.

Comment: Despite iOS 7's release being just around the corner, it is still under NDA so you are not likely to get a good answer until then.

Comment: How are you adding ThumbView as a subview of the UICollectionViewCell?

Comment: Can you post some of your drawing code so that we can have some material to look over and see where the problem lies?

Comment: @ChristianDiLorenzo drawing code is added in question

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code it is hard to say.  I have seen things like this when I run code on a retina versus non-retina simulator and don't properly account for scale difference.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that you're not drawing white lines on a white background in iOS6? (if you're using tintColor in iOS7 for example...)